# Using VIM in read-only mode as the viewer in cscope

Tags: linux, vim, editor, cscope

I tried setting the environment variables VIEWER/EDITOR to: '/usr/bin/vim -R', but, I got the error:
`Cannot exec vim -R: No such file or directory`

Is there a flag in cscope to open up files in read-only mode? Or, can the EDITOR/VIEWER be set to VIM in read-only mode? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is just a problem with whitespace.
The easiest solution is to use `view` which is usually installed with vim. 
It is the same as `vim -R`. Other solutions are just creating simple scripts in your path
that simply call `vim -R`.
Create a file view.sh with

```
#!/bin/sh
vim -R $@
```

then `chmod +x view.sh` and after that you can use this also.

The final option would be to try `'usr/bin/vim -R'` without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Just type 'export CSCOPE_EDITOR=view' in gnome-terminal and then do cscope -R : It will open cscope in read-only mode